# Image is broken after copying to new workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

When I use vba to copy a worksheet to another workbook, one of my image picture will be broken with this error:

```
Dim filename as string
filename = "copyToThisExcel.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open filename:= "C:\myExcelFile.xlsm"
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks(filename).Sheets(1)
```

[image]

This happens randomly on computers and not others. I believe it is a known bug for 2007 and 2010 excel. Is there any workaround this or different alternatives to add images to excel that would not cause this issue?

Here is a link to this known bug.

http://www.spreadsheet1.com/excel-vba-bugs.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to open the destinaion file. Look at this example :

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim filename As String
filename = "myFile2.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\temp\myFile2.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\temp\myFile1.xlsm"
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks(filename).Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't add that part of the code, but yes, it does aleady open the destination file before it trys and open the new file and copy the worksheet over.

Comment: it works as it should 80% of the time, but 20% of the time, the image goes error like above picture and it's a known bug for excel 2007-2010, if you manual copy over, it will be fine 100%, it's just the copying using vba that happens. Trying to find a alternative solution.